# Unable to run Left 4 Dead 2 on Linux Mint after recent Nvidia Update

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, steam

I'd managed to capture the dialogue box and it read:

Failed to create GL context; could not create GL context: BadValue {integer parameter out of range for operation}

Do I have to wait for an update on Valve's part, or is there a solution that I can immediately implement?

I don't want to break anything (as I so often do), so I'm asking for advice.

Any and all admissions are appreciated!

After checking other games, I'd noticed that L4D2 is the only game that outputs this text. Everything else crashes instantly on launch.

Comment: have you rebooted since the update?

Comment: Have you reinstalled the drivers? Perhaps the install was messed up.

Comment: ( https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=210915 ) Refers to CS:GO, but I *think* cs:go was built on L4D2 codebase.

Comment: Reset fixed the issue, thank you. I didn't figure on resetting, though I probably should have.

Comment: Thankyou, you can answer your own questions and accept them so that the site has the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux package managers will remove an old version's files when installing an update.  Your graphics driver update likely did this -- no interruptions to anything you had running already, but newly loaded programs failed to find the removed files, hence the `Failed to create GL context` errors.  Rebooting loaded the new driver and associated files.

With some drivers (eg VirtualBox host drivers), it's possible to unload the old versions after the update (`rmmod`) and load the new versions (`insmod` or `modprobe`) without rebooting.  This is not possible with graphics drivers.

Keep an eye on future updates; you may want to hold off applying kernel or driver updates until a reboot is convenient.